# Difficulties with modelling Latitude and Longitude on Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coordinates

I'm having some troubles with modelling the Earth with a sphere and using another sphere as a marker to mark the latitude and longitude position of the Earth sphere.

I've set the x,y, and z scale to 635.6752 as that is the 1000:1 scale of the Earth's radius in metres. I'm using the latitude and longitude positioning of London.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Earth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ObjectEarth;
    public Transform ObjectMarker; // ObjectMarker object
    public float radius = 635.6752f; // globe ball radius (unity units)
    public float latitude = 51.5072f; // lat
    public float longitude = 0.1275f; // long


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        ObjectEarth.transform.localScale = new Vector3(radius, radius, radius);

        latitude = Mathf.PI * latitude / 180;
        longitude = Mathf.PI * longitude / 180;

        // adjust position by radians   
        latitude -= 1.570795765134f; // subtract 90 degrees (in radians)

        // and switch z and y (since z is forward)
        float xPos = (radius) * Mathf.Sin(latitude) * Mathf.Cos(longitude);
        float zPos = (radius) * Mathf.Sin(latitude) * Mathf.Sin(longitude);
        float yPos = (radius) * Mathf.Cos(latitude);


        // move ObjectMarker to position
        ObjectMarker.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos, zPos);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

And here is the output in Scene View:

[image: Output of the code in Scene View of Unity3D Editor]

I'm not quite sure why the marker object is so far away from the surface of the Earth object, theoretically, it should be on the surface of the Earth object.

Any help and suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity's sphere primitive has a base radius of 0.5 units. So to make the sphere's radius `radius`, you need to set the scale to twice that value:

```
ObjectEarth.transform.localScale = 2f * radius * Vector3.one;
```